# When alt-tabbing, subfolders in Netrw change appearance and opens in preview window

Tags: netrw, macvim

I'm on macOS Ventura 13.2, using macVim and terminal vim. When I toggle Netrw, open a folder with a subfolder, and then cmd-tab away from vim and back again, that subfolder changes appearance and opens as a file would, in the preview window to the right of Netrw.

Here's a short video showing it more clearly: https://streamable.com/i18s4p

This also happens with terminal vim. Here's another video: https://streamable.com/qfyp50

Netrw-wise, I have these settings in my .vimrc:

```
set autochdir
let g:netrw_liststyle       = 3 
let g:netrw_preview         = 1     
let g:netrw_banner          = 0 
let g:netrw_winsize         = 25    
let g:netrw_browse_split    = 4 
let ghregex='\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+'
let g:netrw_list_hide=ghregex
```

Is there a solution to this? Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: Cmd+Tab is notoriously buggy/weird in Ventura so it might be yet another bug/weirdness like sending an unexpected keycode.

Comment: Huh okay, maybe I’ll just have to wait for a fix then, thanks!